# three.js this.renderer.setViewport why not work on IE browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js

> this.renderer.setViewport(50, -50, this.width, this.height);

**Why not work on IE browser?**

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer was depreciated in r126 ([see release notes](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r126)).

You'll have to provide polyfills for APIs like `Array#from` to use a more recent version. Modern build systems target a [browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to transpile/polyfill this for you.